# Mac OSX cmd works from command line, fails from php shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell, command-line, wkhtmltopdf

I am on Mac OS X 10.9.4

I can run this command successfully from the command line to produce an image or google.com

```
wkhtmltoimage http://www.google.com /Users/me/Sites/google.jpg
```

But when I tried to execute the same command from inside my website using the php command

```
$cmd='wkhtmltoimage http://www.google.com /Users/me/Sites/google.jpg';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: wkhtmltoimage: command not found
```

Is this a permission issue?  If so how can I get it to work?

====

## Update

I set the full path like @Mureinik suggested and I made some progress now the error message I get is

```
Loading page (1/2)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[=============>                                              ] 23%
[==================>                                         ] 31%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
[========================>                                   ] 41%
[=====================================>                      ] 62%
[=======================================>                    ] 65%
[========================================>                   ] 67%
[=========================================>                  ] 69%
[==========================================>                 ] 71%
[==============================================>             ] 78%
[==================================================>         ] 84%
[===================================================>        ] 86%
[============================================================] 100%
Rendering (2/2)                                                    
[>                                                           ] 0%
[===============>                                            ] 25%
Error: Could not write to output file                             
Error: Could not save image
[============================================================] 100%
Done                                                               
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

Am I having a permission issue now?

====

## Update

I changed the file permission to my destination and that took care of it.

Comment: Try adding 2>&1 at the end of your command to catch error messages

Comment: I did, that is were I got the error message above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is probably that `shell_exec` uses a different `$PATH` then you, and thus can't locate `wkhtmltoimage`.
From you own shell, you can use `which wkhtmltoimage` to determine where exactly it's installed, and then use `shell_exec` with the full path, e.g.:

```
$cmd='/opt/wkhtmltoimage http://www.google.com /Users/me/Sites/google.jpg';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: IMHO it's better to append to the `PATH` (with `putenv()`) than to use a full pathname, since that's much more robust & portable.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That depends on specifics.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles across this answer, my command involved saving an image into a directory and `shell_exec` didn't have write permissions for that directory. Me as a user *did* have rights which is why I was able to execute the query manually successfully.

So I just changed the permissions of the directory so that it could be written to.